# What's a good event-based to-do list manager?

Tags: calendar

Let's say I have to buy some superconducting magnets in my local store, but it's not particularly urgent; I'll just buy them whenever I'm near that store.

Let's say I have to go through some safety interlocks at various locations every now and then and in order to do so I have a particular retinal-scanning procedure to go through each time.

How could I store to-do items like this? They are not based on time, so are not suited to a calendar, and they are not simple items on a list to do at any-old-time. They are *event-based*: I buy the magnets when I'm at the store; I get the retinal scan when I'm going through interlocks.

What kind of program (open source) do I want for this? I would want the to-do item "buy superconducting magnets" to appear when I'm near the store (maybe I tell it; maybe it figures that out) and I would want the retinal scan procedure to appear whenever I'm going through an interlock.

Comment: Nice question.. I don't think that you'll find such thing. In concept todo list is attached to time driven, so I don't think you can find an answer for your question.

Comment: Thanks. I had figured that it might be possible to add an item and to add tags to it. A tag could be a location, a date or anything else. When you use the manager, you enter or select a few tags corresponding to a given event and the manager returns the best to-do item matches.

Comment: So you want a gps/location reminder app that I can only see being useful if on a phone? With say the ability to set from desktop

Comment: At a basic level, I'm happy just to select a few tags and see relevant items appear. At a more advanced level, Ubuntu Touch could be a nice place for such a program with GPS and so on available easily.